# Unbound DNS (Redirection of LAN)

Tags: iptables, unbound

I'm trying to redirect my LAN queries to local DNS server (installed in LAN) instead of default DNS ie 8.8.8.8.

I'm using unbound 1.13.1 and tried the following:

1. tried localzone

local-zone: "10.in-addr.arpa." transparent
domain-insecure: "10.in-addr.arpa."
forward-zone:
name: "10.in-addr.arpa."
forward-addr: 192.168.0.228

2. Changed module config to respip validator

   define-tag: "tag1 tag2 tag3"
   access-control-tag: 10.0.0.0/8 "tag2 tag3"
   access-control-tag-action: 10.0.0.0/8  "tag2" redirect
   access-control-tag-data: 10.0.0.0/8  "tag2" "A 192.168.0.228"

Also, tried redirecting via iptables (PREROUTING) but thats also not working.

My first objective is to do this via unbound config. Please help!!

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: I'm trying to redirect my LAN queries i.e. 10.0.0.0/8 to my captive portal hosted at 10.10.10.10.

Comment: Got it. It is always better to state the original purpose [in the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1100476/edit).